# I want to show the LaTeX results in a RMarkdown document when the function produces LaTeX code

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

When using the `library(matlib)` in `R`, I can produce LaTeX code. I want to knit a RMarkdown document and I want the LaTeX **result** to show and not the LaTeX **code**.

For example:

```
library(matlib)
A <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2)
matrix2latex(A)
```

produces this result:

```
## \left[
##  \begin{array}{rr}
##   1.00 & 3.00 \\ 
##   2.00 & 4.00 \\ 
##   \end{array}
## \right]
```

Instead of showing the **code**, is it possible to show the LaTeX **results**, like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose the result in a `displaymath` environment (using `$$`) and use the `results='asis'` chunk option:

````
```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
library(matlib)
A <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2)
cat("$$")
matrix2latex(A)
cat("$$")
```
````